# Asimov's novel with a world divided into floors

Tags: story-identification, novel, isaac-asimov

Each floor had different patterns, there was a kind of elevator. I remember a general ambience, but not quite what the plot was about.

The protagonist was a kind-of apprentice (or not?) from another reality who was, amongst others, discovering the subsequent floors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The End of Eternity](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2009) by Issac Asimov (1955)

Eternity is a time traveling organization that tries to optimize human history.

They use a kind of time machine called a "kettle", which operates much like an elevator. Different historical epochs are like different floors. Naturally each era is different. In one, the style for room decor is to make all the walls and furniture like mirrors.

Eternity organization is located in a separate time continuum from the one that contains Earth. Eternity recruits apprentices from the Earth continuum and brings them into the Eternity continuum.